# Is it possible to secure swf files?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If we create an online SWF application, is there any way to secure it so that someone else doesn't download it and put it on their site? For instance, Webkinz is made with Flash,  yet nobody is pirating it on their servers with the whole game unlocked. What is Webkinz doing that we can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Webkinz isn't pirated because...well...let's face it, who wants Webkinz??? hehe

Comment: How do you know Webkinz has not pirated?

Answer (score 6):

1- Obfuscate your ActionScript using an advanced obfuscator such as [secureSWF](http://www.kindi.com).

2- Domain lock your SWF files.

3- Create a dummy loader, rename the original SWF files and change their extension, then load the original SWF files using the dummy loader.

4- Make sure to prevent hot linking. (this will depend on your web server)

5- Encrypt sensitive strings in your ActionScript; either manually in your code, or you can also use secureSWF for that.

Comment: The original SWF file can be found out by decompiling the dummy loader, still it is a way of adding security

I think I came up with an alternative.I will post in on my blog soon

Comment: yes, but the original will be obfuscated and domain locked. Not useful!

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that all the answers in here are variations on ways to make it more difficult or annoying for someone to re-host your flash. There is no way to *prevent* someone from doing it, unless your ability to obfuscate your defenses exceeds the attacker's ability to de-obfuscate them.

As for what I'd do, I'd sprinkle my code with bits like this:

```
// in a display object
if ( loaderInfo.url != "http://example.com/my/real/content.swf" ) {
    // blow up
}
```

That should stop anyone who doesn't have access to a decompiler. If that's not good enough, the only answer is to invest in an obfuscator, because nothing else you do is going to make any difference unless your code is obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it difficult to steal your swf files if you do like Webkinz does, in that they have one main movie that is embedded in the page (so user's know the url of that movie). All subsequent movies are loaded in that original movie programatically. Of course someone with a flash decompiler could decompile your movie and see the paths, but then again you could even go through the trouble of making the names of those MovieClips obscure.

Answer (score 1):

We have extensively tested all of the swf tool in the market and not one except secureswf does the job. However, it's not without it problem either where my swf is found broken after applying many combination setting. Frustrated, I decided to use a better idea with PHP which is similar to how "Copy Protected Audio CD" work.

A demo showing how PHP can be use to secure your SWF.
http://wildfiremedia.com.sg/demo.php

Answer (score 1):

Believe me,PHP won't protect your SWF.I've been working on SWF Security for many years,I can bypass any secured or so-called encrypted SWF.

There's no 100% security of SWF,but if you want to know how to make it as secure as possible,I can help.You can reach me at swfprotection at gmail.com

Remember,PHP cannot protect SWF.

Answer (score 0):

That mostly depends on your web server software. If PHP, you can use readfile().
See the example [here](http://us.php.net/readfile). Store the .swf itself above the webroot, then use some authentication before calling readfile. In this setup, you'd call the php file with your readfile() call in place of the .swf.

So it might look, in an extremely simplified way, something like this:
fakeswf.php:

```
if (authenticate()) {
    header("Content-Type: application/flash");
    readfile("../realswf.swf");
    }
else {
    header("Content-Type: text/html");
    echo "Nothing to see here.";
    }
```

index.html:

```
<a href="fakeswf.php">Click here to play my game</a>
```

As far as the browser is concerned (if you properly set the headers as per the example), fakeswf.php is a .swf file.

IMPORTANT NOTE: I didn't actually look up the proper content type for a .swf file. Be sure to look it up and change it accordingly.

Comment: Why couldn't people simply retrieve fakeswf.php, then rename it?

Comment: Because the file isn't actually stored in the php file. And if you have a server configuration that allows you to download server-side code, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: Further, in the authentication step, you hopefully take steps to ensure the file is being called from your server.

Comment: The swf isn't stored in the php file on the server side, but on the client side it is. When someone views your site, the web server will send their browser a file called "fakeswf.php" that contains the contents of your swf. The user can simply rename that file.