# flash simple protection

Tags: flash

I need to protect the Fla (swf) I have created and tha I am hosting so it can be run ONLY from mydomain.

It means: if someone copy the swf to HIS domain, the flash will not work.

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to secure swf files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034885/is-it-possible-to-secure-swf-files)

Answer (score 1):

This can be decompiled and removed but its just another layer of security you can add that will crash the app if not on allowed domain(s)

```
var lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
switch ( lc.domain ){
  case "mysubdomain.mydomain.com":
    break;
  case "anydomainallowed.com":
    break;
  default:
    var i:int = 0;
    while(0){
      i += i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of web server you're hosting on, you can restrict users from accessing your .swf file (or the complete .swf file type) outside of the domain it's being hosted on.